# CRM OrganizationServiceProxy authentication issue

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm-2011

We have an issue where our web app calls to CRM via Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk OriganizationServiceProxy are failing to authenticate.  The issue appears to be environment specific i.e. the calls work on our DEV web server but fail when the app is promoted to our System Test environment.  The code that fails is as follows:

```
using (var serviceProxy = this.serviceFactory.Impersonate(userProvider.PrincipalUserName).ServiceProxy)
                {
                    var countResult = serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(query));
                    int? count = 0;

                    var entity = countResult.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (entity != null)
                    {
                        count = (int?)((AliasedValue)entity["activity_count"]).Value;
                    }

                    return count.Value;
                }
```

The error that appears in our logs is:

System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have double checked the apppool identity of the IIS site and CRM settings.  Is there anything obvious here that we may have missed?

Comment: Define by what you mean by double checking the appPool identity of the IIS and CRM settings.

Comment: Checking that the service account used for the app pool identity on the web server can talk to the CRM server (the service account has the system admin role on the CRM server).  There are other CRM LINQ based calls (using the ServiceContext) made by our web app that work with no problems.  The only authentication problems we have are certain calls made by the web app to query CRM via OrganizationServiceProxy and the RetrieveMultiple method.

Comment: Is your system Test environment an IFD?

Answer (score 0):

I found the connection to CRM Online was taking the longest time so I create one instance to pass round of the OrganizationServiceProxy with explicit credentials that I can easily switch between environments.

```
    IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> management = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(new Uri(CrmUrl));

    ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    credentials.UserName.UserName = CrmUserName;
    credentials.UserName.Password = CrmPassword;

    AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = management.Authenticate(new AuthenticationCredentials { ClientCredentials = credentials });
    SecurityTokenResponse securityTokenResponse = authCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse;

    OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(management, securityTokenResponse);
    orgProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
    _xrmService = new XrmServiceContext(orgProxy)
```